# How to validate textbox or Browse button at a time?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have question about how to validate `input type=text` or textbox OR `input type="file"` upload a file at a time using javascript or jquery?

1) If textbox is selected than no need to upload file.
2) If upload file is selected than no need to textbox.
3) Both

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: i made a upload file function with caption if user want only upload a file than no need to add any caption 2 if user can also update only cation like "facebook status". there well no need to update picture. @MehdiBounya

Comment: I mean did you try to solve your problem ? is there any code ? please post it in your question so we can take a look

Comment: Yes, i put required in html and did one javascript. but problem is remains same that's why remove javascript. @MehdiBounya

Comment: check prasad's answer, that would do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple with [`required`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjF4r2Oj_7TAhXLvY8KHR--B-4QFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Ftags%2Fatt_input_required.asp&usg=AFQjCNGVN7nEs7Ws3pW_pqnuxRkD1f-cIw&sig2=oDoS1aQiLJy9meaOHnnvrA) attribute

```html
<form>
<input type="text" required="true">
<input type="file"  required="true">
<button type="submit">validate</button>
</form>
```

Or with Javascript validation

**Updated**

```js
$('button').click(function(){
 var a =$(".validate").map(function(){
  return $(this).val().trim() ? true : false
}).get()
if(a.includes(true)){
console.log('pass')
}
else{
console.log('select any one')
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="validate">
<input type="file" class="validate">
<button>validate</button>
```

Comment: here 1)if i used textbox than error file box can not be empty.

Comment: i can use both or only one field. @prasad

Comment: you need validate any one right .Not empty with both

Comment: i need any one at a time @prasad

Comment: @HackerHate Glad to help.. happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

" Just check both file and text box is empty or not before proceeding further."

```
if(!$('input:text').val().trim() && !$('input:file').val().trim()){
alert('Enter required data');
}
```

Comment: i want any one at a time